# Blurry text on Android 4.4 webviews

Tags: android, webview, blurry

Text in my app's WebViews display very blurry on Android 4.4.   Works fine in prior versions of Android.   Also displays properly after I rotate the device (even if I rotate back to the original orientation.)   Anyone know what is causing this?
[image]
Here's a screenshot:

Comment: Post the code. Maybe then someone can help.

Comment: are you testing it on the same device..there might be problem with the resolution.

Comment: It worked fine on the devices before they got the Android 4.4 upgrade.  I'm working on stripping the code and layouts down to a minimal amount of code to try to figure out what seems to trigger this behaviour.

Comment: @JohnWeidner but which library u use for blur webview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the hardware acceleration was causing the problem.   Adding

android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

in the AndroidManifest.xml for the particular activity made the problem go away.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26374&q=blurry&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: This problem has persisted even to Marshmallow, and this solution still works! Thanks!